# Unable to submit form to freecodecamp mock url

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to submit the form

I've checked my code thoroughly for hours and looked at posts on freecodecamp forums but it seems to me I still cannot submit the form and I can't pinpoint the problem.

```
<form action="https://www.freecodecamp.org/email-submit" id="form">
   <div class="email-box">
   <label for="email">Email: </label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email here.." required>
   </div>
   <div id="submit-box">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
   </div> 
  </form>
```

When I click the #submit element, the email is submitted to a static page (use this mock URL: https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit) that confirms the email address was entered (and that it posted successfully)

Answer (score 4):

The error states:

```
AssertionError: The #email input should have a name attribute : expected false to equal true
```

So, add name attribute:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter email address"id="email" name="email" required><br>
```

For any help check [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/product-landing-page-test-submit-element/199810/12).